# Access child members within parent class when children are inside a vector of type parent

Tags: c++

I have multiple child classes inside a parent class vector where each child has it's own type. The parent has a virtual `getType` function and each child overrides it with it's own; not even sure if I need this TBH but I got from this [Access child members within parent class, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190952/access-child-members-within-parent-class-c)

When I loop over the vector (loop not shown here), the type is only that of the parent, since it's a vector of Parents, but I need the type of each individual child made with it's own constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Parent 
{
  private:
  string type = "parent";
  public:
    virtual string getType()
    {
      return type;
    }

};
class Child1 : public Parent
{
  string type = "type1";
  public:
    string getType()
    {
      return type;
    }
};
class Child2 : public Parent
{
  string type = "type2";
  public:
    string getType()
    {
      return type;
    }
};
//main.cpp
int main()
{
   vector<Parent> children;
   Child1 t1;
   Child2  t2;
   children.push_back(t1);
   children.push_back(t2);
   //THIS WORKS
   cout << t1.getType(); // returns type1
   // I NEED THIS TO WORK
   cout << children[0].getType(); // returns parent. 
   cout << children[1].getType(); // I need type1 && type2

}
```

How can I do this? I have no way of knowing what type of child each is otherwise, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Sorry if I miss the point, but there is no constructor in your classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just experimented *slicing*.

A `Child` is a `Parent` plus a few more things.

When you try to put a `Child` in the vector of `Parent`, only the `Parent` part of each of these `Child`ren is put in the vector (because the vector does not contain `Child`ren but `Parent`s); hence the name *slicing*.

In order to obtain the dynamic polymorphism you are looking for, you need a vector of *pointers* to `Parent`; this way, each pointed-to element can be whether a `Parent` or a `Child` and behave accordingly.

This is often done with a dynamic allocation of each element in the vector, but this is not mandatory. For example, you could store all the `Parent`s in a vector, all the `Child`ren 1 in another, and so on, and finally use a vector of pointers to designate some of them in any order.

If you decide to allocate each `Parent`/`Child` individually, you should consider smart-pointers like `std::unique_ptr<T>` rather than raw pointers and `new`/`delete`.

You will find below  your example slightly modified in order to obtain dynamic polymorphism.
It relies on dynamic allocation of each element thanks to `std::unique_ptr<T>`/`std::make_unique()`.

Note that, because of dynamic polymorphism, you need a `virtual` destructor (even if it does nothing special).
Since this hierarchy of types is intended for dynamic polymorphism, it is encouraged to prevent slicing (that you have just experienced) by forbidding the use of copy/move operations.
Thus, you have to provide one or several constructors that fulfil your needs (but this is quite common).

My last advice is « avoid dynamic polymorphism; prefer `template` » but it is another topic ;^)

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr<T>, std::make_unique()

class Parent 
{
public:
  virtual ~Parent() =default; // ensure correct destruction

  // forbid copy and move in order to prevent slicing
  Parent(const Parent &) =delete;
  Parent &operator=(const Parent &) =delete;
  Parent(Parent &&) =delete;
  Parent &operator=(Parent &&) =delete;

  Parent() =default; // provide a suitable constructor

  virtual
  const std::string &
  getType() const
  {
    return type;
  }
private:
  // inline static // is probably better
  const std::string type{"parent"};
};

class Child1: public Parent
{
public:
  const std::string &
  getType() const override
  {
    return type;
  }

private:
  // inline static // is probably better
  const std::string type{"type1"};
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
  const std::string &
  getType() const override
  {
    return type;
  }

private:
  // inline static // is probably better
  const std::string type{"type2"};
};

int
main()
{
  const auto p=Parent{};
  std::cout << "p: " << p.getType() << '\n';
  const auto c1=Child1{};
  std::cout << "c1: " << c1.getType() << '\n';
  const auto c2=Child2{};
  std::cout << "c2: " << c2.getType() << '\n';
  auto people=std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>{};
  for(auto i=0; i<2; ++i)
  {
    people.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Parent>());
    people.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child1>());
    people.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child2>());
  }
  for(const auto &e: people)
  {
    std::cout << e->getType() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For more information on slicing in C++ see this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).